# What is an efficient way of traversing a graph with bfs using map reduce?

Tags: algorithm, graph, mapreduce, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

This was an interview question I got asked by a recruiter, the problem is basically to calculate the shortest path of all node to every node, and my solution was the following

initiate all possible edges (without reverse A - B is the same as B-A)

Each node will be represent in the following (src, cost, current_list, dest) , the src and dest is basically all the possible edges we initiate earlier

Map:

```
for each edge you traverse, you duplicate your tuple and add the current   
traversed node to the cost and current list. 
if the node is the destination you annotate finish, if the the node is 
in the current list, you annotate delete
```

Reduce:

```
Don't really need to do anything besides outputting finish and deleting 
delete and let the other node go through the next round of map
And by outputting I mean for each src, dest pair only output the least cost
```

The recruiter say this is not efficient, I can see how this is not efficient since you are traversing combinatorialy, but the only alternative I can think of is if you have n node, then spawn n servers and do dijkstra for each node which the recruiter say is also wrong. Can someone give me some help on this problem?

Edit:

Ex. Triangle Graph

The edges are A-B, B-C, C-A with path cost of 1

Algorithm

1. First we initiate all possible source destination pair keeping in mind that reverse of edge is not unique
   A-B, A-C, B-C   (B-A, C-A, B-C is omitted)

for each source destination pair we have the following tuple

```
(src=A, cost=None, current_list=A, dest=B, annotate=continue)
(src=A, cost=None, current_list=A, dest=C, annotate=continue)
(src=B, cost=None, current_list=B, dest=C, annotate=continue)
```

2. Now we start the map reduce algorithm

   ```
   for each tuple in the tuple list we initiate:

       for each neighbor of the node at the end of current_list
           if the next neighbor is already in the current_list
               set annotate = delete
           elif the next neighbor is the dest
               set annotate = finish
               add path cost to cost
           else
               duplicate the current node
               add neighbor to current_list
               add path cost to cost
           delete the current tuple
   ```

In our case

```
(src=A, cost=None, current_list=A, dest=B, annotate=continue)
 =>
(src=A, cost=1, current_list=AB, dest=B, annotate=finish)
(src=A, cost=1, current_list=AC, dest=B, annotate=continue)

(src=A, cost=None, current_list=A, dest=C, annotate=continue)
=>
(src=A, cost=1, current_list=AC, dest=C, annotate=finish)
(src=A, cost=1, current_list=AB, dest=C, annotate=continue)

(src=B, cost=None, current_list=B, dest=C, annotate=continue)
=>
(src=B, cost=1, current_list=BC, dest=C, annotate=finish)
(src=B, cost=1, current_list=BA, dest=C, annotate=continue)
```

3. Reduce

   Note: we reduce on src, dest pair, and use it as our key
   for every tuple in tuple list

   ```
   if annotate == finish
       keep trace of min cost and delete tuple for each src dest pair that is not the current min
       then pass the current min as result
   elif annotate == delete
       delete the tuple

   else
       pass down to the next round of map
   ```
4. Map

Since we still have some tuple that have annotate = continue

```
(src=B, cost=1, current_list=BA, dest=C, annotate=continue)  
=>
(src=B, cost=2, current_list=BAC, dest=C, annotate=finish)  
(src=B, cost=2, current_list=BAB, dest=C, annotate=delete)  


(src=A, cost=1, current_list=AC, dest=B, annotate=continue)
=>
(src=A, cost=2, current_list=ACB, dest=B, annotate=finish)
(src=A, cost=2, current_list=ACA, dest=B, annotate=delete)

(src=A, cost=1, current_list=AB, dest=C, annotate=continue)
=>
(src=A, cost=2, current_list=ABC, dest=C, annotate=finish)
(src=A, cost=2, current_list=ABA, dest=C, annotate=delete)
```

5. Reduce

We have no continue tuples, now we just use the reduce to find the min for each src dest pair

Comment: What you described is not even solving the single-source shortest path problem with MapReduce correctly, if I would be your interviewer I wouldn't be worried about efficiency in the first place, but correctness.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, the reduce part only output a source node destination node pair that have the least cost, and I traverse all possible path from A to B, where A and B is arbitrary

Comment: So you don't want the all-pair shortest paths, but the minimal cost edges between two vertices?

Comment: I keep track of both the shortest path and the minimal cost edge, since I have a current list variable I pass around, if the cost turns out to be the minimal cost, then the current list must be the shortest path in terms of cost, and you can have the current list as a linked list or an array where you keep track of the traversal order

Comment: If I have n nodes, I calculated the shortest path (like A->B->C) and the minimal cost for each node to n - 1 other nodes (that is shortest path from vertex to vertex). My algorithm does not calculate a minimum spanning tree

Comment: I tried REALLY hard to understand your algorithm (because I think I'm simply misunderstanding it). Can you please add a simple example for the triangle [A <-> B = 1], [A <-> C = 2], [B <-> C = 1]. And real pseudo-code might also help. I have no clue what you mean by `annotate` and which key are you reducing on?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut , I edited with your example, but with all cost 1, I am reducing on src dest pair. By the way, I just want to mention that I might be solving the problem in the wrong direction, and my solution might be completely wrong, but I am just not sure what is wrong with it

Answer (score 4):

The inner two loops of Floyd-Warshall are essentially matrix multiplication with addition replaced by min and multiplication replaced by addition. You can do matrix multiplication with a map-reduce, so you can implement Floyd Warshall with |V| map-reduces.

From the wikipedia page on Floyd-Warshall:

```
1 let dist be a |V| × |V| array of minimum distances initialized to ∞ (infinity)
2 for each vertex v
3    dist[v][v] ← 0
4 for each edge (u,v)
5    dist[u][v] ← w(u,v)  // the weight of the edge (u,v)
6 for k from 1 to |V|
7    for i from 1 to |V|
8       for j from 1 to |V|
9          if dist[i][j] > dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] 
10             dist[i][j] ← dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]
11         end if
```

The inner two loops (`i` and `j`, lines 7 to 11) are structurally the same as matrix multiplication, and you can adapt any "matrix multiplication on map-reduce" solution to perform this.

The outer (`k`) loop becomes |V| map-reduces.

Comment: Good idea, I was thinking about FloydWarshall yesterday too. Coming back to efficiency, do you think running a job per vertex is a good idea?:)

Comment: Sadly a paper that claims to do it with three mapreduce executions is behind a paywall http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6425603&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D6425603

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose the following approach - for finding of shortest paths in graph via map-reduce.

Lets start with tiny example, which will lead to intuition regarding further implementation of algorithm.

Imagine, that information about graph is stored in form of **adjacency lists** (with payload, which represent paths between corresponding nodes). For example:

`A -> [ {B, "A-B"}, {C, "A-C"}, {D, "A-D"} ]`

From given example - we can "infer" information about the following connections in graph:

1) Direct connections

- `A -> B` (path: `"A-B"`)
- `A -> C` (path: `"A-C"`)
- `A -> D` (path: `"A-D"`)

2) Transitive connections through node `A`

- `B -> C` (path: `"B-A-C"`)

  (where `path("B -> C") == reverse(path("A -> B")) + path("A -> C")`)
- `C -> B` (path: `"C-A-B"`)
- `C -> D` (path: `"C-A-D"`)
- `D -> C` (path: `"D-A-C"`)
- `D -> B` (path: `"D-A-B"`)
- `B -> D` (path: `"B-A-D"`)

In other words: we just **"mapped"** one entry of adjacency list - to multiple pairs of mutually accessible nodes (for all of generated pairs - there exists a path).

Each pair of nodes, actually represents connection: `Source -> Target`.

So, now, we can **combine** all pairs - which has the same source node:

`Source -> [{Target 1, "Path-to-Target-1"}, {Target 2, "Path-to-target-2"}, ...]`

Actually, after the combination - each source will be associated with a list of target nodes: **list might contain duplicated target nodes** (duplicated target nodes, just corresponds to different possible paths).

So, we just need to remove duplicates from list of target nodes (to keep only that target nodes, which corresponds to the shortest paths).

Two paragraphs from above - actually describes **reduce** step.
The output of reduce step - is the same as input to **map** step.

So, finally - just repeat these map-reduce steps until convergence.